# C - Display all lines from a c executable in a file for debugging purpose

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols

I'm having issues with a c program that I want to debug.
I would like to know how to get a file that contains every lines of my executable, so I can later set breakpoints with gdb in it.
Thanks :)

Comment: @alk Indeed it's gcc, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GCC specify `-g` when compiling.

More here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html